# How to Import API from XML file using Azure API Management REST API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I am trying to import API in Azure API Management service using API Management REST API.

I tried following two approaches but faced issues:

1) Using the Azure API Management XML Structure.
     -> I Exported existing API in XML from the portal

[image]

-> Created Class using xsd tool. The implementation of calling the REST API is here.

[image]

Error:

{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
 {
   Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 09:58:10 GMT
   Content-Length: 309
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 }}

2)I did same thing my own XML Structure which is available here

[image]

but facing same Issue kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to discussions here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d62a4351-7ef3-4a9d-bb3f-beea6d90d321/how-to-import-api-from-xml-file-using-azure-api-management-rest-api?forum=azureapimgmt

Comment: It is still unanswered, but marking as answer to track at only one place.